# Android SDK not working issues with 'find_java.exe'

Tags: java, android

Android SDK Manager is not working I tried opening it from the eclipse 
and even tried using sdkmanager.exe but its not opening up

I tried all the possibilities and also reinstalled SDK 

console log:
"F:\Android\sdk\tools\lib\find_java.exe" -s' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

can anyone please solve my problem

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have not set your java home path in your machine properly.

set your `JAVA_HOME AND JRE_HOME` variables to the appropriate paths.

Add the environment variable `JAVA_HOME` which points to your java installation directory and then try running eclipse.

Refer this [link](https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=set%20java_home) to set environmental variables. :)